# How do I get data with an Ajax rest call from an API on my HTML site

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, parsing, token

I'm trying to build an application with Javascript where I get football/soccer statistics from football-data.org and put the information I want on my HTML Page.

I have been trying to get the information, however I do not know how I should get it with an AJAX call.

```
$(function (){

    var $players = $('#players');
    $.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'MYAPITOKEN....' }, 

  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PD/scorers',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(players) {
    $.each(players, function(i, player){
       $players.append('<li>name: '+ player[3] +', position: '+player.nationality+'</li>');
       });
  }
   });

});
```

I want to see the player name and postion, however I get this on my html page as a :

name: undefined, position: undefined

name: undefined, position: undefined

name: undefined, position: undefined

name: undefined, position: undefined

name: [object Object], position: undefined

This is what the log says:
[Console log Api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I7Xj.jpg)

Comment: This isn't really about AJAX but about using the loaded object and its children / elements. Add `console.log(players);` to your `success` callback and study the data in the console. It would also help if you linked us the part of the API docs showing an example response of your specific request.

Comment: Thanks. this is what i get in the console log. The part which i want to get is scorers.https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I7Xj.jpg

Comment: I'd rename `players` to `data`, then use `$.each(data.scorers, function(i, player) { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than you need something like this:

```
$(function (){

  var $players = $('#players');
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'MYAPITOKEN....' }, 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PD/scorers',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $.each(response.scorers, function(i, scorer){
        $players.append('<li>name: '+ scorer.player.name +', position: '+scorer.player.nationality+'</li>');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

They have really good documentation and response example on their site (however the response is not complete, but with `console.log();` you can find the missing structure): https://www.football-data.org/documentation/quickstart .

BTW why you write the nationality as a position?

Comment: Thank you very much, 2 minutes before you made this code i had already found it out by going deeper into the player data. Thanks again. I indeed had to do: scorer.player.name.